# Trigerring hooks for user-defined events

Tags: juju

If I look at the MySQL charm (https://jujucharms.com/precise/mysql-48/?text=mysql#code) it includes a lot of hooks. According to my understanding each hook is triggered by Juju runtime when deploying a resource or some change happens to a relationship between resources. How can I trigger a hook when a certain user-defined event (CPU utilisation > 95%) occurs?.

Does Juju support to specify user-defined events or do I need to write an external script to automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no user-defined events that Juju responds to at this stage.

Yes you would need to write an external script.

Juju does have the ability to run commands in the context of a unit (like a hook).

This is done using the 'run' command from the command line, or if being run from cron on the machines themselves, the command is 'juju-run'.